# Exponential distribution - greater-/eqal, lower-/eqal, eqal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm currently going through some known probability distributions and I'm stuck at the exponential distribution.

Here is an example task:

> You are in a super market standing in a queue. You know that the
>   average waiting time is $4$ minutes. Assume that the waiting time $X$
>   (in minutes) is exponentially distributed. What's the probability that
>   you need to wait...
>
> (i)  exactly $3$ minutes?
>
> (ii) more than $4$ minutes?
>
> (iii) between $2$ and $7$ minutes?

If I understood the exponential distribution correctly, I will need to use its distribution function to calculate these probabilities, which is given by

$$F(t)=P(X<t)=\begin{cases} 1-e^{-\lambda t}&\mbox{if }t \geq 0\\
0&\mbox{else }\end{cases}$$

(i) I'm not sure and leave it away for now.

(ii) $P(X >4) = e^{-\frac{1}{4}\cdot 4}$

(iii) $P(2\leq X \leq 7)=P(X\leq 7)-P(X \leq 2) = 1-e^{-\frac{1}{4}\cdot 7}-\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{4}\cdot 2}\right)$

---

(ii) and (iii) should be fine, I hope. But what about (i)?

Comment: For a continuous distribution, the [probability value at a specific point is zero](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/142736/67822). It's a measure theory issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a continuous distribution, the probability value at a specific point is zero. It's a measure theory issue:

---

For discrete probability spaces, the sample space is countable (finite or infinite), and it will either be $\Omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2,\cdots,\omega_n\}$ or $\Omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2,\cdots\}$.

We can afford to take the set of all possible subsets of the sample space as the sigma algebra, $\mathcal F = 2^\Omega$, i.e. all subsets of $\Omega$ are events, and hence, will have assigned probabilities.

We assign probabilities to all the subsets of $\Omega$, or in this case, events $\bf A$, via the assigned probabilities to singletons, $P(\{\omega\})$.

So, $P(\bf A)= \displaystyle \sum_{\omega\in A} P(\{\omega\})$.

Whatever way probabilities are assigned, it should satisfy that $\displaystyle \sum_{\omega\in \Omega} P(\{\omega\})=1$.

However, in the case of **continuous distributions (uncountable sample spaces over the real line)**, it is not possible to assign probabilities to $\mathcal F = 2^\Omega$ since $\Omega$ is uncountable. $2^\Omega$ has higher cardinality than the real numbers. We can't assign probabilities to, for example, $[0,1]$,based on adding up the probabilities of singletons.

The most common way to assign probabilities is using intervals $(a,b)$ is $b-a$. We want

$$\mu((a,b)) = \mu((a,b])=\mu([a,b))=\mu([a,b])=b-a.$$

From there we can see that if $b-a=0$ (i.e. the probability assigned to a singleton, $\Pr\left(\{\omega\}\right)$), as in the case of $\Pr(X=3\text{ min})$ in the OP, the probability will be zero.

I bet that was the intention behind the inclusion of the word "exactly" in the question.